# Has anyone else had trouble saving categories with a lot of products?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

We have a category with around 12,000 products and when I try and save it, the page just spins for a few minutes then I get an internal server error.
The errors are connection is reset or timeout errors. But I can't imagine that it should take this long to save the category.

Update to this: It seems to time out with any category we have tested so far with at least 4000 products. It doesn't even have to be a category with 4000 direct products, even a category that has sub-categories with products totaling 4000+ won't save. The default category will save though, which is odd.
Has no one else had this issue?

Comment: Connection time out leads to set `memor_limit`. Try to use Flat Catalog then Save

Comment: tried flat and it still didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also have experienced this issue.

On category save, it is creating rewrite urls for all the sub categories and their products. Due to this, if there is lots of sub categories and products, timeout error comes.

This functionality should be removed from category save and put in re-indexing.

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, have not checked it, as i got busy with other websites. Need to check later after upgrading magento, if they have fixed it.